# Spring Boot : Getting @Scheduled cron value from database, but database value may be changed and need to fetch changed value without restarting APP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to schedule an API in spring boot by taking the time constant from the database. I can implement it with @Scheduler and found solutions to fetch from the database and was able to do so. But, when the app is running and I change the database value, it is taking the same previous value to schedule. Not the updated one. How can I achieve dynamic scheduling so that my API is scheduled dynamically by taking the value from the database and when the database value is changed, it should fetch that changed value without restarting the spring boot app?
Any suggestions would be helpful.

I couldn't implement it.

Comment: IMO, when you change the value of '@Scheduler', the app has to recompile to work, and I do not think it's practical. Instead, it would be best if you tried another solution without the dynamic value for the annotation like setting your '@Scheduler' to a smaller fixed time then taking the time range and last run from your database and comparing them